# Specflow Scenario Outline with multiple scenarios

Tags: specflow

I was wondering if any one had gotten the following cucumber to work with specflow.

```
Feature: testing different user types

Scenario Outline:Validate User RBAC 
Given I have a new User
And The new user can login <username> and <password>

Examples:
|username|password|
|xxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyy|


    Scenario:Test 1
       Then something 
    Scenario:Test 2
       Then something else
    Scenario:Test 3
       Then some other thing
```

I can get the Scenario Outline to work.
However there are series of tests I want to do with different users and creating a different user for each test is slowing down my tests.

There is this example but I think there may be an error in the code, sorry If I'm incorrect. See: http://toolsqa.com/specflow/data-driven-testing-using-examples-keyword-in-specflow/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same scenario executed with different users, you have to use scenario outlines for every one and define them in the example table.